# Get class functions from webpack module

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I need to call class function, what writed in webpack module from outside script.

There is webpack config:

```
 entry: {
    main: ["./src/js/main.js"],
  },

  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js"),
  },
  optimization: optimization(),
  module: {
    rules: ifBabel(),
  },
```

In main.js i have

```
import { finishing } from "./modules/forms/finishing";

var fns = new finishing();
fns.init();
```

I need to call some function of fns from outside script. But webpack compiling script inside his function and i cant access to it..

Comment: *I need to call some function of fns from outside script.*  Then you'll have to `import` it there, too. This is the intended way modules work.

Comment: What is the logic that is outside, and why is it outside instead of inside the Webpack bundle like everything else?

Comment: Filter writed in frontend in webpuck, but script, what calls this filter in cms, i need to call it from body. <script> tag</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 primary options:

- Use Webpack's [`library`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) to define how your Webpack bundle exposes itself to the page when loaded, and have your `main.js` export functions to be used by your page via the library, like

  ```
  import { foo } from "./foo";
  export { foo };
  ```

  with the page then able to use `LibraryName.foo()`
- Have `main.js` explicitly do something like

  ```
  import { foo } from "./foo";
  window.foo = foo;
  ```

  to manually expose specific functions on the window or some other location.

I would recommend the first approach, but either is fine.